# What to Do About Inaccurate Dates on Letters of Recommendation?

Tags: recommendation-letter

As part of the application for a fellowship at an university, I acquired two letters of recommendation.

Apart from a factual inaccuracy in the body of one letter, which I am going to mention in the motivational letter, both of the letters I've got are stamped to a wrong date. One is dated earlier than the application for the fellowship was released (January instead of February, though the day isn't accurate either, lol). The other one is dated to the day before the application is due, while I received it a couple of days before that.

Should I worry about these inaccuracies and mention them in the motivational letter? I don't think it's particularly important, especially for the latter one, which contains a sensible date (though the 'date created' definitely shows a different date from the one signed), but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for such inaccuracies. Copy and paste is one. Inattention is another. But none of them that I can think of are your fault, and none seem to be attempts at sabotage.

As such, I would ignore the issue, especially in written documents in which you have more important and positive things to write. If you are asked about them, your reply can be just that the writer likely made a mistake and if it needs correction, you can probably handle it then.

Use your motivation letter for precisely that. Don't use it to apologize for the errors of others.